# Automatically fill all available space in a CSS grid row

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I have a dynamically generated CSS Grid layout with `grid-row` values which are set using a script. It looks something like this:

```
╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 1/2 │
│               │
╰───────────────╯
╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 2/4 │
│               │
│               │
│               │
╰───────────────╯
╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 4/5 │
│               │
╰───────────────╯



╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 6/7 │
│               │
╰───────────────╯
```

When two elements have the same `grid-row` value, they are automatically displayed on the same row, like so:

```
╭──────╮
│ :1/2 │
│      │
╰──────╯




╭──────╮ ╭──────╮
│ :3/4 │ │ :3/4 │
│      │ │      │
╰──────╯ ╰──────╯
╭──────╮
│ :4/6 │
│      │
│      │
│      │
╰──────╯
```

How can I get the elements to automatically fill all available horizontal space, like below?

```
╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 1/2 │
│               │
╰───────────────╯




╭──────╮ ╭──────╮
│ :3/4 │ │ :3/4 │
│      │ │      │
╰──────╯ ╰──────╯
╭───────────────╮
│ grid-row: 4/6 │
│               │
│               │
│               │
╰───────────────╯
```

Comment: Can you provide some `HTML` and `CSS`? I don't think anyone will be able to help otherwise. My only guess is you might try `grid-auto-flow: column;` element with `display: grid;`

Comment: Not possible with Css-grid. That is what flexbox is for.